# Is there a way to select all items within a circular buffer?

Tags: qgis, sql, buffer, multipoint

I want to select all the items within a circular buffer. Inside the buffer are
multipolygons and multipoints. See the screenshot i have posted.

[image]

Comment: how are you defining the buffers? are they based on a point layer, or precomputed? or do you want to select by hand using a radius? all are possible

Answer (score 1):

You need to select points and polygons separately.

In order to select points:

1. Use `Vector > Spatial Query` *
2. In Select Source features from : select your points layer (to be selected)
3. Where the features : select `Contains`
4. Reference features of : select your buffers layer
5. Click Apply
6. Points included in buffers are now selected (you can save this selection as a new layer or apply specific symbology or do anything you want with them...)

Do the same for your polygons layer. If you want to select polygons that are partially included in buffers, you will then choose the Ìntersects`option for`Where the features`option of the plugin.

(*) if not available in your QGIS, install *Spatial Query Plugin* through `Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins...`

Comment: Is there a way you can see the spatial query that is used by vector?

Comment: The spatial query result is displayed directly in the map canvas (selected features are colored differently).

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. It can be done with the spatial query plugin.
Once enabled, go to 
`Vector ‣ Spatial Query ‣ Spatial Query` and follow the wizard.

Comment: `@Stefan`: I answered accurately mentionning this plugin.